# Excel summing values based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following excel sheet, and I want to sum values based on an a match value and effect code.

```
Effect Code   Value   Match Code  Numerator    Denominator
      2        500      111000    
      8        700      111000
      2        900      111000
      8        560      111000
      5        100      211000    
      8        200      211000
      7        300      211000
      8        750      211000
```

Now the numerator is the sum of all match codes with an effect code equal to 8 and the denominator is any effect code that is not 8. so I would like to get the following:

```
Match code    Numerator    Denominator

  111000        1260           1400
  211000         950            400
```

I have Hundreds of thousands of rows in the excel spreadsheet which I would like to do this on. I have tried using the following to do the summation, however it is not working properly and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it:

```
=SUMIF(Match_Code,C2,Value)
```

The other problem I will have with the type of solution above is that I will have a bunch of duplicates of the Match Code, when in the end I just want one with the values of the numerators and denominators summed up. Any other solutions that could get around this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: [`Pivot Table'?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)

Comment: Does it have to be a formula?  I agree with Scott, from what i understood, you might have less trouble using a pivot table, using the filter and sum functions it provides

Comment: @Mister832 No it doesn't have to be a formula. A pivot table is a good idea I hadn't thought of. I got caught up in one idea in my head and my mind just shut out everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abandon the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) and use more criteria with a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B).

```
=sumifs(Value, Match_Code, C2, Effect Code, 8)
=sumifs(Value, Match_Code, C2, Effect Code, "<>8")
```

Comment: OP: you can copy `Match Code` column and use [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) to get a unique list to run these formulas against.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think I see what you are getting at. That's a good idea!