# Excel: how to NOT sum based on text values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am trying to sum values based on another text column.

Let's say my data look like this:

```
date              item              amount
4/3/03            book              100
8/3/05            rent              1090
5/6/06            food              5
2/7/09            repair            390
8/3/10            rent              1090
```

so I want to sum all the spendings (amount) when the "item" section is NOT equal to "rent", but I dont just want a grand sum, I just want a sum that's up to that date. 
So the desired output (last column, subtotal) should look something like this:

```
date              item              amount          subtotal
4/3/03            book              100             100
8/3/05            rent              1090            100 
5/6/06            food              5               105
2/7/09            repair            390             495
8/3/10            rent              1090            495
```

I've tried to sum it up while filtering the rolls to only show anything but rent, but when I clear the filter, all the numbers will sum INCLUDING rent.

I've also tried using SUMIF (I named the top cell in "Amount" column as "first_amount"):

```
=SUMIF(C2,"rent",first_amount:E2)
```

But I dont think I'm using it correctly or maybe it just doesn't work. It shows no value whatsoever.

I found this post and read through the function pages, but still am not being able to do what I wanted to do:
[Excel summing values based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665772/excel-summing-values-based-on-multiple-conditions)

**BONUS:**
What if I want to exclude both "rent" and "food"?

I'm sure there's a very simple solution out there that I am just too dumb to think of. Any hint/help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A1` is the first cell make `D1`:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:B2, "<>rent", $C$2:C2)
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you! what if i want to make sure it does not include both "rent" and let's say "food"?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions look at the `SUMIFS()` formula